# Как добавить в SQL базу строку в C#?

Tags: sql, c#

Как добавить в SQL базу строку в C#. Я делаю так:

```
public DataTable cd;
...
cdaDataSet.Tables["leq"].Rows.Add("8", textBox1.Text);
```

Но в базе не добавляет.

Answer (score 4):

Примерно так. Предполагается, что поля Вашей таблицы имеют имена ID и Name.

```
var cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [leq] ([ID], [Name]) VALUES (@id, @name)", conn);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", "8");
cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", textBox1.Text);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Можно ещё использовать SqlDataAdapter.Update - тогда соответствующую команду надо перед вызовом будет присвоить его свойству InsertCommand

Comment: на SqlCommand подчеркивать как ошибку
The type or namespace name 'SqlCommand' could not be found

Comment: using System.Data.SqlClient;