# Добавление данных в бд из коллекции

Tags: c#, sql, база-данных, list, datagrid

Собственно, есть 2 грида, один заполняется коллекцией, данные в коллекции - данные из бд.

Метод заполнения коллеции

```
 public List<Food> GetFoods()
 {
     List<Food> Foods = new List<Food>();
     string query = "select * from Food";
     MySqlConnection sqlcon = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString);
     MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, sqlcon);
     cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
     sqlcon.Open();
     MySqlDataReader sqlreader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
     object[] row;
     while (sqlreader.Read())
     {
         row = new object[sqlreader.FieldCount];
         sqlreader.GetValues(row);
         Foods.Add(new Food()
         {
             Name = row[0].ToString(),
             Belki = (decimal)row[1],
             Jiri = (decimal)row[2],
             Uglevodi = (decimal)row[3],
             Ccal = (decimal)row[4],
             Voda = (decimal)row[5],
             FoodID = (int)row[6],
         });
     }
     sqlreader.Close();
     return Foods;
 }
```

Заполнение грида из коллекции

```
 FoodProvider p = new FoodProvider();
 List<Food> food = p.GetFoods();
 GridOne.ItemsSource = food;
```

В процессе работы программы во второй грид (вторую коллекцию `List<Food>`) добавляются или удаляются записи. Мне необходимо, чтобы по клику на кнопку, содержание второй коллекции добавлялось в бд. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как инсертнуть коллекцию.

Comment: во-первых, при чем тут InvalidCastException? Если вы его где-то ловите, то где и как? Во-вторых, при чем тут первый грид, если в вопросе вас интересует добавление данных из второго? В-третьих, что именно не получается при добавлении данных в бд?

Comment: Прошу прощения за заголовок, это мой первый вопрос в stackowerflow, раньше хотел задать другой вопрос, но нашел решение проблемы, сейчас появился этот вопрос а заголовок остался из прошлого не запощенного вопроса. Могу ли я править заголовок?. Первый грид тут при том. что каждый грид заполняется своей коллекцией. Суть вопроса в том, как добавить каждый элемент коллекции в бд, не знаю как это сделать.

Comment: ну и что, что каждый грид заполняется своей коллекцией?  При чем же тут первый грид-то? Туманно объясняете. 
Плюс вы не ответили на третий вопрос - что конкретно не получается при добавлении данных в бд? Кроме того, что у вас за грид?

Comment: Если у вас появился другой вопрос - задавайте его отдельным вопросом.

Comment: Да дело не в гриде, он тут не причем, просто не умею изъяснятся, извените еще раз. Всё дело в том, что я не знаю, как добавить каждый элемент коллекции в бд. Не получается потому что не знаю :(

Comment: Справа, в связанных вопросах висит http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/7314/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2-sql-%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%83-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b2-c?rq=1

Comment: @PashaPash Спасибо,  я знаю как инсертнуть одну строку, я не знаю как это сделать для всей коллекции.

Comment: Так же, ручками в цикле по одной строчке и добавлять. Для прохода по всей коллекции можно использовать цикл for-in.

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант, сделать цикличное перечисление элементов коллекции и insert каждого элемента в базу. Либо попытаться связать коллекцию с dataset и использовать его.

Answer (score 0):

Для того, чтобы занести всю коллекцию в базу, необходимо в цикле foreach перебрать все эелементы коллекции и добавить каждый элемент в базу, спасибо @AlexKrass